# What is the bigger difference in this case when using case or if?

Tags: bash, case

I always use `if` for this type of stuff, and I haven't really thought of it, but lets say something simple like this:

```
case $1 in
test)
echo "test"
;;
test2)
echo "test"
;;
test3
echo "test3"
esac
```

vs.

```
if [[ "$1" == "test" ]]
then
echo "test"
elif [[ "$1" == "test2" ]]
then
echo "test2"
elif [[ "$1" == "test3" ]]
then
echo "test3"
fi
```

What are the bigger differences in this case? Is any of them objectively better for another task?

Comment: Please see the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018037/which-is-faster-of-two-case-or-if

Answer (score 3):

`case` compares the value of a single shell *word* to any number of specified shell *patterns* *(if any)* and executes the associated shell *list* *(if any)* for the first of these found to match or nothing at all. `case` evaluates the *word* and each associated pattern up to the first matching such only once. `case` returns for any executed shell *list* or else 0.

`if` compares the value of the *return status* of some required shell *list* to 0 and subsequently executes the required `then` shell *list* if it matches or else executes the optional `elif` or `else` shell *list* *(if any)*. `if` executes and evaluates the return of at least one shell *list* for every `if` statement in any chain of `if`s with an associated *list* that returns 0.

`if` returns for any executed `then` or `else` list, or else 0 regardless of the required `if` shell *list*'s return.

Answer (score 2):

A `case` test several patterns against a variable, `$1` in your example.
Several `if ... elif` may make any test, including several patterns against a variable, but that is just an special case of the general `if ... elif`.